# Quantifying shape of polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon

I want a quantification technique to differentiate different shapes of polygons. For example, the following image consists of 3 seperate polygons, e.g., (a) is stretched to its tails, (b) is bowl shaped, and (c) is a complex polygon.

[image]

Is there any geometrical way to differentiate these phenomenon?

For instance, if I want to segregate only the bowl shaped polygons, what would be the technique in GIS?

I dont want to use any kind of pattern recognition techniques, just looking for a geometrical solution in ArcGIS.

Comment: What has your research to date indicated?

Comment: One observation I have made is the ratio of perimeter (shape_length) to area is higher in A and C than in B, C is a bit more tricky, you could look at the convex hull containing the geometry and erase it with the geometry, C should have a higher *outside area* than B. How are you planning to implement this? What API/Language(s) do you plan to use? The best you're going to get is a value for *stretchyness* and *complexity*, which you will need to apply an arbitrary limit to determine what category the geometry falls in.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelStimson for your insights. The points you have mentioned seem interesting. I can only think of ArcPy for this work right now. As I have a lot of polygons to work with, I can implement these factors, e.g., ratio of length to area, and difference of convex hull geometry and shape geometry. Then, I can do a binary logistic regression to see which factor has higher importance in this classification. I will post the final findings.

Comment: That would be most interesting, have a read of polygon.convexHull() and polygon.difference() http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Polygon/018z00000061000000/ to help with the difficult part. Assume your geometry is Geom then OutsideArea = Geom.convexHull().difference(Geom).area (make a convex hull and erase the inside returning the area)... you could do this on an arcpy.da.updateCursor and have a quantifiable value to work with (along with shape_length and shape_area if you're in a geodatabase, if you have a shapefile then you will need to get these from the polygon).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use some shape characteristics, e.g. orientation, elongation, convexity, rentangularity, compactness etc.

- Orientation is direction angle of long axis of minimum area bounding rectangle (MABR) of a polygon.
- Elongation is the ratio of the length of the MABR’s short axis to long axis.`(b/a)`
- Convexity is the ratio of the polygon area to the area of its convex hull. `area(Polygon)/area(ConvexHull)`
- Rectangularity is the ratio of polygon area to MABR area. `area(Polygon)/area(MABR)`
- Compactness/Roundness is the ratio of the area of the circle with the same length as the polygon to the polygon area. `area(Circle)/area(Polygon)`

[image]

Then, you will come to a conclusion by comparing them. For example:

- If compactness value is close to 1, it's almost bowl shaped.
- If convexity is big, it's a complex polygon.
- If elongation is far far away from 1 and orientation is close to 90 degree, it is  stretched to its tails.

For further information, you may read this article: [Performance of shape indices and classification
schemes for characterising perceptual shape
complexity of building footprints in GIS](http://www.tandfonline.com/eprint/xHV9kRWBN4X5MyQxKiPu/full)

Comment: The [Minimum Bounding Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/minimum-bounding-geometry.htm) tool may be some help in creating data to use in some of these tests.