# Symbolize thousands of polygons to identify similar geometries

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, mapping, spatial-query

I would like to categorize polygons with a similar enough geometry so such similarities can identified at a city-wide scale.

I'm trying to identify if street layout is a useful spatial characteristic for differentiating between neighbourhoods. I have polygonized a shapefile with road lines. Next, I tried symbolizing the resulting polygons based on area using a gradient ramp. Using an equal count mode with 21 classes this symbology does do a good job at 1:10000 scale to differentiate blocks with a widely road layout. However, blocks that are short and more squat are not differentiated much from blocks that are long and thin (that have a similar area). Also, this way of symbolizing is pretty much useless at a city-wide scale. It may require a different approach at 1:10000 vs 1:45000 to identify such differences, and I would like to do both, but for now I would settle for a solution for the neighbourhood level.

[image: An example of symbolizing by area]

[Some other questioners](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253479/polygon-shape-similarity-using-qgis) have been directed to use a script that employs a hausdorff distance for detecting similarities between polygons. While this may prove to be a useful method, I'm not sure how I would use this to compare numerous polygons to each other.

I'm in the early research stages of my studio class, so the solution doesn't need to be precise. I was thinking that perhaps I could add a bounding_length and bounding_width field to each polygon and populate it with the field calculator. Then, perhaps I could look at the data and identify some commonalities. Then, to another field (perhaps poly_similarity_id) I could classify polygons with a query such as the following psudocode `"SELECT * WHERE bounding_length < 20 AND bounding_length > 25 AND bounding_height < 110 AND bounding_height > 100"` that would set poly_similarity_id to 1. I could run another query to select polygons with a different length/height range that is common and set that to 2, etc, etc. Then I could symbolize based on these new categories.

I have used ArcGIS several times over the years and done a couple of classes on it, but I'm still a novice at best. I'd need to figure out how to do all the above again. I'm also new to QGIS. Before I do all that, would this method work? Would there be a better way to go about this?

I'm thinking that if I can get such a categorization of similar polygons, then I can remove all the other non-pattern-conforming ones. Then, coloring the clusters that fit a pattern black, those patterns would stand out at a city scale.

Comment: Your select statement is going to fail because `bounding_length < 20 AND bounding_length > 25` is impossible.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/278429/29431

Comment: Thanks for the the correction Bjorn. Kadir, that's extraordinarily helpful. I'm still experimenting with the different options in that link to see how I can best represent the data. My gratitude.